# apache redirect /url1/* to /url1/index.html

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, virtualhost

I changed the context url from:
`domain.name/url1` to `domain.name/url2`

I want to have a 301 redirect of all URLs from

`domain.name/url1/*` to the static file `domain.name/url2/moved.html` and show a static *maintenance* page

The rewrite rules should not take into account any other URLs except `domain.name/url1/*` for this redirect

`url1` and `url2` are subfolders in the apache directory `/var/www/home/`

The apache configuration is:

```
Listen 9082
<VirtualHost *:9082>

ServerName domain.name

DocumentRoot "/var/www/home"

<Directory />
  Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/home">
  Require all granted
  RewriteEngine on
  AllowOverride all

</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
</IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this code in your `url1/.htaccess`:

```sh
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule . /url1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I edited the question to show the apache configuration. since your solution would impact url2 subfolder also

Comment: `your solution would impact url2 subfolder also` : How did you reach to this conclusion? `RewriteRule ^uri1/. uri1/ [NC,L]` will only impact `url1/`

Comment: I tried your solution and when I check `domain.name/url1/iy8yaigsdfg` it shows a `Not Found` and when I checked `domain.name/url2/` it is redirecting to `domain.name/url1`

Comment: Copy/paste your full .htaccess in question and you must clear your browser cache

Comment: I made an update. Use this code **as is** in `url1/.htaccess`

Comment: is it possible to have a redirect since the Google bot will not see this change

Comment: the redirect is not showind the domain.name anymore but the `hostname:port/url1`

Comment: When `/url1/` is used then redirected URL keeps same domain name as in the original request. So if your source URL is `hostname:port/url1/iy8yaigsdfg` then redirected URL would be `hostname:port/url1/`

Comment: However if you want you can change last rule to `RewriteRule . http://domain.name/url1/ [L,R=301]`